# Why does gdalwarp return incorrect corner coordinates for my geotiff?

Tags: web-mapping, coordinates, gdalwarp

I have a png source image that's in Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area and I have the long/lat extent. So I ran gdal_translate to create tie points and convert to gtif. Then I ran gdalwarp to reproject to Web Mercator. gdalinfo shows that the bounding coordinates are ok for the gdal_translate output, but not for the gdalwarp output. Que pasa?

Here's my gdal_translate operation on the source file:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs "+proj=laea +lat_0=40. +lon_0=-105 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370997 +rf=298.257" ^
-gcp 0 0 -119.344674 47.148697 ^
-gcp 525 0 -90.655326 47.148697 ^
-gcp 525 431 -93.609897 31.438244 ^
-gcp 0 431 -116.390103 31.438244 ^
-a_ullr -119.344674 47.148697 -93.609897 31.438244 ^
src.png tmp.gtif
```

(I included the bounding box long/lats for good measure but it seems to make no difference in the outcome of gdalwarp.)

Here's my gdalwarp operation on the gdal_translate output (tmp.gtif):

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -s_srs "+proj=laea +lat_0=40. +lon_0=-105 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370997 +rf=298.257" -t_srs EPSG:3857 tmp.gtif final.gtif
```

Here's the metadata from 'gdalinfo tmp.gtif':

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: tmp.gtif
Size is 525, 431
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (-119.344674000000000,47.148696999999999)
Pixel Size = (0.049018622857143,-0.036451167053364)
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
**Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-119.3446740,  47.1486970) 
Lower Left  (-119.3446740,  31.4382440) 
Upper Right ( -93.6098970,  47.1486970) 
Lower Right ( -93.6098970,  31.4382440) 
Center      (-106.4772855,  39.2934705)** 
Band 1 Block=525x3 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 2 Block=525x3 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 3 Block=525x3 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 4 Block=525x3 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

Corner coordinates look good. But here's the metadata from 'gdalinfo final.gtif':

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: final.gtif
Size is 579, 355
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs"],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
Origin = (-11688702.286414048000000,4866004.054033085700000)
Pixel Size = (0.057992644981843,-0.057992644981843)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
**Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-11688702.286, 4866004.054) (105d 0' 5.04"W, 40d 0' 1.53"N)
Lower Left  (-11688702.286, 4865983.467) (105d 0' 5.04"W, 40d 0' 1.02"N)
Upper Right (-11688668.709, 4866004.054) (105d 0' 3.95"W, 40d 0' 1.53"N)
Lower Right (-11688668.709, 4865983.467) (105d 0' 3.95"W, 40d 0' 1.02"N)
Center      (-11688685.498, 4865993.760) (105d 0' 4.49"W, 40d 0' 1.28"N)**
Band 1 Block=579x3 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 2 Block=579x3 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 3 Block=579x3 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 4 Block=579x3 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

Also notice that the pixel size is suspect in the final image - both dx and dy are the same.

Comment: I'm suspicious about the use of +a and +rf. 6370997 is a sphere (almost authalic based on Clarke 1866), not an ellipsoid. So you might try +b=6370997, not +rf=298.257. A lot of US government data in Lambert azimuthal uses a sphere-only implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Mike. I'll try that and compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you seem to be getting very small values is because your original image is projected, so it uses linear units - which in this case PROJ4 I think defaults to metres - rather than degrees. So you're specifying a ~680 square metre part of the western US.

Now, how you can determine the right coordinates to use is a tricky matter because your image covers such a large area, you'll get a lot of distortion at the edges.

Sorry this isn't much of a solution - anyone else care to take over? If I have a flash of inspiration, I'll post it here.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense - that Proj would assume meters since it's projected.

Comment: I started with a projected file and was given a center lat/lon and the spatial extent in meters. So I used proj -I (inverse) to determine lat/lon values of the corners from the initial info, and I used those lat/lon values for gcps. Could I then use proj to get northing and easting for the corners from the lat/lons and use those linear values for gcps? Or is that going to produce the distortion you mention? Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: Ah, but that's circular - it will give me linear values with respect to the center of the image, which I already have. You're saying those linear values will be distorted?

Comment: I just tried it and it worked - I used the corner values in meters from the spatial extent of the original file. Indeed there is some distortion near the edges, but I think it's acceptable for this application. Sincere thanks for the answer.

Comment: Ah, I'm glad you've got it sorted. stackexchange is all about giving the questioner the tools to find their own solutions... well, that's what I'm telling myself :) If you could mark the answer as accepted, that'd be cool.

Comment: You did just that! Well done.